Pantalla roja en flutter


Las imágenes muestran una pantalla roja. Esto es cuando quiero generar una splash screen con una animación. Tienen alguna idea de como solucionarlo. Desde ya muchas gracias.
Saludos

La aplicación parece estar optimizada. Puedes instalar una versión no optimizada para poder averiguar de dónde viene el error? Mira los registros con logcat e incluye más información que pueda ayudar a responder la pregunta

Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor aca. Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

He realizado algunas correcciones:
import 'package:animated_splash_screen/animated_splash_screen.dart';
import 'package: flutter/material.dart';
import 'package: splash/ask_screen.dart';

class SplashAnimationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
 const SplashAnimationScreen({super. Key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AnimatedSplashScreen(
    splash: Center(
      child: Container(
      // * Aquí puedes agregar su imagen, icons o otro widget de tu preferencia.
    ),
  ),
  nextScreen: const AskScreen(),
  splashTransition: SplashTransition.scaleTransition,
  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 107, 159, 248),
);}}

La Column se eliminó porque normalmente se usa para agregar varios widgets, pero en tu caso solo estás utilizando un único widget.
